# php 7 vs 5.6 array declaration

Tags: php, arrays

I recently migrated from php 5.6 to php 7.1.4 and my application shows errors when i try to declare an array within an array in:

```
447 $rblq['response']['result'] = $numbers;
448 $rblq['response']['document'] = $link;
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  Illegal string offset 'result'
>
> Filename:
>   Materiales.php
>
> Line Number: 447
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset
>
> Filename: Materiales.php
>
> Line Number: 448

These are the `var_dump` results for each one:

```
var_dump($numbers) array(3) {
  ["cristales"]=>
  int(0)
  ["porcentaje"]=>
  float(0)
  ["monedas"]=>
  int(0)
}
var_dump($link) string(0) ""
```

I suspect that has nothing to do with `$numbers` and `$link` but with the way I declare the new arrays that don´t exist yet an the moment of the execution:

```
$rblq['response']['result']  
$rblq['response']['document']
```

It was functioning on php 5.6 but with 7.1.4 it doesn´t seem to work.
Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `$rblq['response']` is a string and not an array...

Comment: Show the code that creates `$rblq['response']`

Comment: Hi, I tried converting $rblq['response'] to an array $rblq['response'] = []; and it works the way it was with php 5.6, my question is: Why in php 5.6 it was forced into an array and why it doesn´t work like that in php 7. I read the 'Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x ' from php.net and couldn´t find this specific change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rblq['response']` is a string, `var_dump($rblq);` to see.  Most likely under PHP 5.6 `error_reporting` and/or `display_errors` was off and now it is on.

Find where you set `$rblq['response']` to a string and remove it or `unset` or reinitialize it as an array:

```
unset($rblq['response']);
//or
$rblq['response'] = array();
```

Comment: The output is this
{
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["mesagge"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["response"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
I can see that response is a string, I kind of worked around this with `code`$rblq['response'] = [];
And it worked just fine for the functionality desired.
However, I was wondering why it wasn´t an error in php 5.6. 
I suspect it has something to do with the 'strict types' characteristic, I'll take a look at that. Anyways thanks for your answer!